# Mathematica - "Triangulation" - Drawing a Triangular Grid on a Graph

Tags: grid, wolfram-mathematica, mesh

The picture I attached should say it all: I would like to link-up all the points I have plotted in such a way that a grid of triangles is formed.

Alternatives to triangles are also possible, as long as the results is a nice, almost-regular graph.

[image]

Comment: See the help for `PlanarGraphPlot[]`

Answer (score 4):

As belisarius mentioned in the comments, there is a command for triangulation in Mathematica. It's called `PlanarGraphPlot`. This is how it works:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
g = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 2], {i, 1, 100}];
ListPlot[g, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: A random graph]

```
PlanarGraphPlot[g, LabelPoints -> False]
```

[image: triangulated graph]

Or perhaps, using `Show` you can plot them on top of each other:

```
Show[PlanarGraphPlot[g, LabelPoints -> False], ListPlot[g, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Large, Red}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks Ali and belisarius. Is there a way to get the AdjacencyMatrix from this plot. I've noticed that DelaunayTriangulation[] gives a list which is not in the same format as AdjacencyList and definitely not in the AdjacencyMatrix format. I ultimately want 1 matrix with all the coordinates {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...} and 1 matrix with the edges/links {{0,0,1,1,0},{1,0,1,0,0},...}, i.e. the AdjacencyMatrix. Any idea on how to go from DelaunayTriangulation[] to AdjancencyMatrix?

Comment: @LauBo: you should "accept" the answer if it gave what you were looking for. (click empty checkmark on the left under the votes)